# How to fail a serenity bdd job on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I have quick question - I am running Serenity BDD tests on Jenkins CI. I was wondering if anybody here knows how to fail jenkins job on CI if there is a failure in the feature scenarios (or any failures in general). Also, it would be great if anyone can let me know as to how can i fail Jenkins Serenity BDD job based on a threshold (i.e. only fail the build if more than 80% error). Many thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Serenity build fails, the Jenkins build job should fail automatically. Only failing when there are more than a certain percentage of errors is not supported by Jenkins as far as I know, and would be an odd testing strategy.

Comment: I am able to fail the jenkins job using <goal>check<goal>. Thanks a lot for also looking at the second part of my question and sharing your thoughts. I agree threshold based resulting would be a odd strategy